# Как сделать переадресацию при помощи php и ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

Ajax запросом вызывается php скрипт. В нем завершается текущая сессия и в конце требуется обновить страницу. Делал 2 способами:

```
1-й способ: header ("refresh: 0");
2-й способ: header ("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

В обоих случаях выдает одинаковую ошибку в responseText. Как заставить это работать?

ОШИБКА ТАКАЯ:

> `Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\koxan.ru\www\PHP\authOut.php:11) in Z:\home\koxan.ru\www\PHP\authOut.php on line 15`

Comment: ладно это понятно. мне больше интересно почему из php не получается? Или так вообще нельзя потому что php вызывается с помощью ajax?

Comment: А вы ошибку переведите, мож понятнее станет) Все просто.

Из пхп не получается, потому что вы грузите текстовую страницу, а вместо текста приходит заголовок переадресации (текста *нет*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объяснили уже, что надо после запроса аякса при получении ответа сделать рефреш прямо в яваскрипте! После отправки данных и получения ответа поставьте строку

```
location.reload(true);
```

Пример

```
$.post('куда посылаем',{имя:параметр},function(dates){
    location.reload(true);
});
```

Все. После возврата ответа скрипт просто уйдет в релоад.